# Don't understand flaw of this Critical Section solution algorithm

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, operating-system

Reading http://www.ics.uci.edu/~bic/courses/JaverOS/ch2.pdf and on page 20 there is this:

> The problem is easily solved if we insist that `p1` and `p2` enter their critical sections >alternately; one common variable, turn, can keep track of whose turn it is. This idea is >implemented in our first algorithm below.

```
/* CS Algorithm: Try #1 */
int turn = 1;
cobegin
p1: while (1)
{
  while (turn==2) ; /*wait loop*/
  CS1; turn = 2; program1;
 }
//
p2: while (1)
{
  while (turn==1) ; /*wait loop*/
  CS2; turn = 1; program2;
 }
coend
```

> Initially, `turn` is set to 1, which allows `p1` to enter its CS. After exiting, the process sets `turn` to 2, which now allows `p2` to enter its CS, and so on. **Unfortunately, if `program1` were much longer than `program2` or if `p1` halted in `program1`, this solution would hardly be satisfactory. One process well outside its critical section can prevent the other from entering its critical section, thus violating the requirement 1 stated above**

The part I put in bold seems false to me. Since `program1` executes after the Critical Section and after `turn` gets set to 2, there is nothing stopping `p2` from leaving its wait loop and entering its critical section, no matter what happens in `program1`. Looks like a perfectly fine solution to me.

Am I right? Am I not seeing something?

(NOTE: `p1` is the thread and `program1` is the non-critical part of `p1`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the while(1) loop in each code fragment. As written, it requires the two critical sections to execute alternately.

That may not be much of a problem if the total time for each of the outer loops is about the same. If there is a significant imbalance, such as program1 taking a lot longer than program 2, then p2 would still be limited to running at p1's speed.

Comment: "consider the while(1) loop in each code fragment. As written, it requires the two critical sections to execute alternately." I guess I'm missing some fundamentals here. If that's the case then everything makes sense. But why is that the case? The way I visualise it is that a context switch can occur at any time. So as soon as the critical section of p1 finishes, a context switch happens p2's wait loop ends, and goes along its merry way.

Comment: @MatthewHolmes Suppose p1 does CS1, and then starts a computation that will take 3 hours. p2 does CS2, once, leaving turn set to 1. A few microseconds later, p2 finishes program 2, and gets back to the top of its loop. It gets stuck at "while(turn==1)" for the next 3 hours. turn will stay equal to 1 until p1, 3 hours later, gets around to the top of its loop and executes CS1 again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `program2` takes a very long time to execute while `program1` is very fast. It is true that `turn` will be set to `1` before it executes, allowing `CS1` and `program1` to execute. However, that will set `turn` back to `2`, and it will get stuck there until `program2` finishes up, which as I mentioned, will take a long time. `program1` cannot execute again until `program2` complete.

In this way, `program1` will not get to execute nearly as often as it could, because it is always waiting on `program2` to finish.